# How do you change the xterm cursor to an I-beam or vertical bar?

Tags: linux, xterm

I want to change the cursor in xterm to an I-beam or vertical bar. From what I can see, there may be support for this. My question is what do I insert into my ~/.Xdefaults or ~/.bashrc in order to enable the vertical bar cursor?

Reference:

- Comment stating it's at least *possible* in xterm:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13883326

Comment: Got it :D For steady vertical bar, add to you ~/.bashrc: 'echo -e -n "\x1b[\x35 q"' For blinking vertical bar, add to your ~/.bashrc: 'echo -e -n "\x1b[\x36 q"'

References:

https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=2248

Comment: Added the answer to pastebin so it's indexed by Google: http://pastebin.com/8hRENZhu

Comment: Why didn't you post it as an answer here?

Comment: I tried to but I don't have enough points, or karma, or whatever :/ So, I did what I could until seven hours go by and I'm able to post a complete answer. In the interim I posted the whole answer on pastebin and provided a link to it. Sorry 'bout the confusion :)

Answer (score 8):

Posting what I found so others can find the answer as well.

You can change the cursor by inserting one of the following lines in your ~/.bashrc file (if you use bash):

```
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x30 q" # changes to blinking block
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x31 q" # changes to blinking block also
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x32 q" # changes to steady block
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x33 q" # changes to blinking underline
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x34 q" # changes to steady underline
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x35 q" # changes to blinking bar
echo -e -n "\x1b[\x36 q" # changes to steady bar
```

References:

- https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=2248

Comment: The link is dead.  The content was copied from [xterm #282](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_282), anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The feature wasn't implemented at the time when this question was asked (see [xterm #379](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_379)), but as of writing this in 23 Mar, 2024, Setting `XTerm*cursorBar: true` made the cursor vertical line for me:

[image: Xterm Vertical Line Cursor Preview]